# Numpy arrays with compound keys; find subset in both

Tags: python, numpy, intersect, compound-key

I have two 2D numpy arrays shaped:

```
(19133L, 12L)
(248L, 6L)
```

In each case, the first 3 fields form an identifier.

I want to reduce the larger matrix so that it only contains rows with identifiers that also exist in the second matrix. So the shape should be (248L, 12L). How can I do this?

I would then like to sort it so that the arrays are indexed by the first value, second value and third value so that (3 3 4) comes after (3 3 5) etc. Is there a multi field sort function?

Edit:

I have tried pandas:

```
df1 = DataFrame(arr1.astype(str))
df2 = DataFrame(arr2.astype(str))

df1.set_index([0,1,2])
df2.set_index([0,1,2])

out = merge(df1,df2,how="inner") 
print(out.shape)
```

But this results in (0,13) shape

Comment: Just to clarify, but wouldn't your reduced matrix not still be of size `248L, 12L` as you're only getting a subset of rows, not also a subset of columns?

Comment: Yes, typo, thank you - will correct

Comment: Is there any order in the smaller array? Otherwise this could get rather costly. Maybe you should instead create a set holding the key-3-tuples.

Comment: No, just use `pandas.set_index()` which allows multiple keys, and is efficient. Don't perform contortions in native numpy. pandas is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **pandas**.

[pandas.set_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) allows multiple keys. So set the index to the first three columns (use `drop=False, inplace=True`) to avoid needlessly mutating or copying your dataframe.

Then, [merge(...how='inner')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to intersect your dataframes.

In general, numpy runs out of steam very quickly for arbitrary dataframe manipulations; your default thing should be to try pandas. Also much more performant.

Comment: @user2290362: please post reproducible code using a random seed to create data.

Comment: I have fixed that, it needed on=[0,1,2] in the merge